# Getting a List of files from a class path entry

Tags: java, classpath

I am facing a problem in my application that I cannot list all the resource from a class path entry.

```
Enumeration<URL> resources = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResources("src/main/resources/*.*");
System.out.println(resources);
while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
  URL url = resources.nextElement();
  //Here I am getting an empty URL list.Please help.
  System.out.println(url);
}
```

Comment: hmm r u sure src folder is accessible from where the code is running? try it with absolute path

Comment: see my class path entry <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/resources"/>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The are couple of problems:

1. **`src/main/resources/*.*` is not valid syntax for `ClassLoader.getResources()`**

   - the path must be full path, e.g. `src/main/resources`
2. **Why are you trying to load classes from `src/main/resources` directory?**

   - it assumes that the resources are in such directory, but that would work only for development purposes
   - after the compilation the resources will be stored in a different directory (Maven will put it top level directory by default) and your program will not work correctly

Answer (score -2):

I think such resources that are read should be put inside folder 'META-INF':

src/main/java/META-INF

Then you can read like following (better specify your file types more specifically than I do):

`ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
        Enumeration<URL> resources = cl.getResources("META-INF");
        while (resources.hasMoreElements()) {
              URL url = resources.nextElement();
              System.out.println(url);
            }`

Comment: Not answering the question.